# android prevent activity closing after open another activity

Tags: android, android-activity

How can I prevent my dialog activity closing by itself when a new window of the system is opened? I just saw this in Facebook messenger:

[image: explanation]

Comment: Facebook messenger doesn't use Activities.  It's a system window.  See here - http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics

Comment: @Jahnold please any example about system window i search for month i didn't find  also if you talk about the _bubble_ i know its window alert i talk about the View or activity that's contain _ReyclerView_ i don't think its View . why because there are also _ViewPager_ and i fail to add _ViewPager_ in View without Activity so that's mean this in messenger must be an activity and not a View

Comment: @Jahnold also you can detect of phone rotate without an activity and cannot detect press back button many problem you will have if i use a View

Comment: You can see using UI Automator Viewer that the whole thing is part of the same ViewGroup (chat-head & chat dialog).  It's not using RecyclerView or ViewPager just *lots* of nested FrameLayouts & LinearLayouts.  The logic is powered by a service.